# Displaying dropdown in Django forms by first 'key'

Tags: python, django, forms, dictionary

I am trying to make dynamic dropdown option list in my django forms, but i cant display it by first dictionary 'key'. 
My choice dictionary in forms is containing two keys, 'name' and 'email'. And it is displaying options by second key('email'), instead of 'name'.

Here is what i mean

 My model:

```
class Supervisors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
```

My form:

```
supervisors = []
all_supervisors = Supervisors.objects.all()
for user in all_supervisors:
    one_supervisor = {user.name.__str__() : user.name, user.email.__str__() : user.email}
    supervisors.append(one_supervisor)

class PrintForm(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    contact_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    supervisor = forms.ChoiceField(choices=supervisors)

    content = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Textarea
    )
```

And my view:

```
def print(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PrintForm(data=request.POST, request = request)

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = request.POST.get(
                'contact_name'
                , '')
            contact_email = request.POST.get(
                'contact_email'
                , '')
            form_content = request.POST.get('content', '')
            supervisor = form.cleaned_data['supervisor']
            supervisor = dict(form.fields['supervisor'].choices)[supervisor]
            # Email the profile with the
            # contact information
            template = get_template('threeD/email/contact_template_for_printing.txt')
            context = Context({
                'contact_name': contact_name,
                'supervisor': supervisor,
                'contact_email': contact_email,
                'form_content': form_content,
            })
            content = template.render(context)

            email = EmailMessage(
                "New message from " + contact_name,
                content,
                "Message - " + supervisor + ' ',
                [supervisor],
                headers={'Reply-To': contact_email}
            )
            email.send()
            messages.success(request, "Thank you for your message.")
            return redirect('/index/print/')

   else:
            form = PrintForm(request=request)
   context_dict = {}
   context_dict['printers'] = Printer.objects.all()
   context_dict['form'] = form
   return render(request, 'threeD/print.html', context_dict)
```

The good thing about the code is that it works and sends emails as it suppose, but my problem is that i have to show dropdown list by names, but it shown me the dropdown list by emails instead.

That's what it does:
[image]
Any help would be very much appreciated, cause i got stuck :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with changing your model's `__str__` or `__unicode` method, add this method to your model `Supervisors`:

```
# change method name to __unicode__ if you are with Python 2.x
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

With this, all instances in any query made to your model will return `name` field's value.

Secondly and to improve your form structure, try this:

```
class PrintForm(forms.Form):
    supervisor = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[
(supervisor.email, supervisor.name) for supervisor in Supervisors.objects.all())
```

One more thing, it is better to change your model name to `Supervisor`. Since classes are templates for a particular objects, it is better to name them with singular names.

Comment: glad to help you!. It is better if you vote answers helped you :) @IljaLeiko

Comment: It is OK :)  have a nice day! @IljaLeiko

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
class PrintForm(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    contact_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    supervisor = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[(str(sup.email), str(sup.name)) for sup in Supervisors.objects.all()]
    )
```

And the code to fill the `supervisors` list is not needed.

Comment: Oh, great! Thank you, it worked! I had to delete 
"supervisor = dict(form.fields['supervisor'].choices)[supervisor]" line from my views, cause it was messing with email recipient, but now it works and works great! Thank you

Comment: @IljaLeiko glad it helped